# Error: No controller

Tags: angularjs

I have two directives, and I'd like to expose an API in one of them for others to use.  Following the guidance from [this example](http://www.egghead.io/video/angularjs-directive-to-directive-communication/) I'm getting this error when I require the other directive's controller:

```
Error: No controller: foo
    at Error (<anonymous>)
    at getControllers (http://localhost:3000/vendor/angular/angular.js:4216:19)
    at nodeLinkFn (http://localhost:3000/vendor/angular/angular.js:4345:35)
    at compositeLinkFn (http://localhost:3000/vendor/angular/angular.js:3953:15)
    at publicLinkFn (http://localhost:3000/vendor/angular/angular.js:3858:30)
    at <error: illegal access>
    at Object.Scope.$broadcast (http://localhost:3000/vendor/angular/angular.js:8243:28)
    at http://localhost:3000/vendor/angular/angular.js:7399:26
    at wrappedCallback (http://localhost:3000/vendor/angular/angular.js:6780:59)
    at wrappedCallback (http://localhost:3000/vendor/angular/angular.js:6780:59) <bar class="ng-scope">
```

My directives are defined as follows:

```
})
    .directive('foo', function() {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            template: '<h1>Foo</h1>',
            controller: function($scope) {
                $scope.someArray = [];

                this.doStuff = function() {
                   $scope.someArray.push('abc');
                }
            },
            link: function(scope, element, attrs) {

            }
        }
    })
    .directive('bar', function() {
        return {
            require: 'foo',
            restrict:'E',
            template: '<h1>Bar</h1>',
            link: function(scope, element, attrs, fooCtrl) {
                element.bind('mouseent', function() {
                    fooCtrl.doStuff();
                })
            }
        }
    })
```

Does anyone know why the second directie can't see the first directive's controller?

Thanks,

Answer (score 4):

`require` property in directive definition object injects the controller(s) to the linking function.

*But*: The directive does not initiate on its own, you need also declare the `foo` directive in the element. Like: `<div foo="hello" bar="world"></div>`.

Also, it has 2 prefixes which can be combined.

1. `?`: "Make requirement optional", no errors are raised.
2. `^`: "Look for it in the parent elements", normally the required directive iw expected to be at the same element. This makes it search in the parent elements.

Comment: Is it possible to achieve this with two directives that are 'E' restricted?  Let's say that both foo and bar are element directive, and a button defined in bar's template has an ng-click that calls a method in its directive scope.  I want that method to then call a method exposed by foo's controller.  Should I consider a different approach?

Comment: @reptilicus Me too and I can't find a manual explaining why it happens.

Comment: As I understand it, you can only have one element tag in an HTML node. One would have to be an attribute. I.e. <foo bar></foo> would make foo the element, bar the attribute. Closing tags don't have attributes.